# LINQ pivot top 5 rows to columns

Tags: c#, linq

The desired output is a set of rows containing details about a physician and the top 5 procedures they performed (by volume) that are not in our benchmarking tables - with a minimum of one per month.  Even with my limited LINQ experience, I have managed to get this working, but the performance in abysmal.  In the spirit of becoming better at LINQ, I thought I'd see if there was a better way to approach this (besides coding in SQL).

Here is the entire method, although I believe it is the final statement (var report =) that deserves the most attention.

```
//Get the Providers for the selected AccessLevel & Report Period
var providerRiskLevels = GetProviderRiskLevelForAccessLevel(userAccessLevelId, reportPeriodId, providerNamePiece);

short benchmarkYear = (
        from rp in db.ReportPeriods
        where rp.ReportPeriodId == reportPeriodId
        select rp.BenchmarkDataYear
        ).FirstOrDefault();

byte Duration = (
        from rp in db.ReportPeriods
        where rp.ReportPeriodId == reportPeriodId
        select rp.Duration
        ).FirstOrDefault();

//Summarize counts by procedure code (ignoring modifiers)
var codeCounts =
    from pp in db.ProviderProductions
    //332 - restrict to valid codes
    join pc in db.ProcedureCodes on pp.ProcedureCode equals pc.ProcedureCode1
    where pp.ReportPeriodId == reportPeriodId
        //show deleted codes as potential issue
        && pc.TerminatedDate == null
        && (codeFilter == null || pp.ProcedureCode == codeFilter)
    join pc in db.PspsProcedures
        on new { col1 = pp.ProcedureCode, col2 = benchmarkYear } equals new { col1 = pc.ProcedureCode, col2 = pc.Year } into left
    from l_d in left.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where l_d == null
    group pp by
        new { pp.ProviderId, pp.ProcedureCode }
        into g
        orderby g.Key.ProviderId, g.Sum(x => x.Volume) descending
        where g.Sum(x => x.Volume) > Duration
        select new NewCodesEntity
        {
            ProviderId = g.Key.ProviderId,
            ProcedureCode = g.Key.ProcedureCode,
            Volume = g.Sum(x => x.Volume)
        };

//Get top 5 procedures performed by provider
var newCodes =
    from cc in codeCounts
    group cc by
        new { cc.ProviderId }
        into g
        select new ProviderNewCodesEntity
        {
            ProviderId = g.Key.ProviderId,
            Codes = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Volume).Take(5).ToList()
        };

//Build the report
var report =
    from pr in providerRiskLevels
    join nc in newCodes on pr.Provider.ProviderId equals nc.ProviderId
    where pr.RiskCategoryId == RiskCategoryIds.VisibleRisk
        && (filterRiskLevelNums.Contains(pr.RiskLevelNum))
        && (filterSpecialtyId == 0 || pr.Provider.Specialty.SpecialtyId == filterSpecialtyId)
    select new ProbeAuditEntity
    {
        ProviderId = pr.Provider.ProviderId,
        ProviderName = pr.Provider.Name,
        ProviderCode = pr.Provider.ProviderCode,
        SpecialtyName = pr.Provider.Specialty.Name,
        SpecialtyCode = pr.Provider.Specialty.SpecialtyCode,
        VisibleRisk = pr.RiskScore,
        NewCode1 = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volume).FirstOrDefault().ProcedureCode,
        NewCode2 = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volume).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().ProcedureCode,
        NewCode3 = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volume).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().ProcedureCode,
        NewCode4 = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volume).Skip(3).FirstOrDefault().ProcedureCode,
        NewCode5 = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volume).Skip(4).FirstOrDefault().ProcedureCode
    };
return report;
```

I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Your best bet for this type of thing is to start by profiling the query that LINQ generates.  That being said, the first thing I would look at are the five `NewCode` properties. If you replace them with: `NewCodes = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volumn).Select(c => c.ProcedureCode).Take(5)` does anything change?

Comment: @JasonBoyd, that was a pretty good "first thing" - reduced query time by 33% and SQL lines by 48%. Thanks for the approach

Comment: I realize why I avoided that earlier - Not all rows will have 5 ProcedureCodes and the Telerik grid I am binding this to (as model.ProcedureCode[x]) throws an out of bounds exception when it encounters someone with a list of less than 5 entries.  I'll try to figure that out so I can continue in this direction.

Comment: LINQ has your back.  Check out my proposed solution.  It should work but I do not have real data to test it against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try for the report:

```
//Build the report
var report =
    (from pr in providerRiskLevels
    join nc in newCodes on pr.Provider.ProviderId equals nc.ProviderId
    where pr.RiskCategoryId == RiskCategoryIds.VisibleRisk
        && filterRiskLevelNums.Contains(pr.RiskLevelNum)
        && (filterSpecialtyId == 0 
            || pr.Provider.Specialty.SpecialtyId == filterSpecialtyId)
    select new 
    {
        RiskLevel = pr,
        NewCodes = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volumn).Select(c => c.ProcedureCode).Take(5)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new ProbeAuditEntity
    {
        ProviderId = x.RiskLevel.Provider.ProviderId,
        ProviderName = x.RiskLevel.Provider.Name,
        ProviderCode = x.RiskLevel.Provider.ProviderCode,
        SpecialtyName = x.RiskLevel.Provider.Specialty.Name,
        SpecialtyCode = x.RiskLevel.Provider.Specialty.SpecialtyCode,
        VisibleRisk = x.RiskLevel.RiskScore,
        NewCodes = x.NewCodes.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(<DefaultProcedureCodeHere>, 5)).Take(5)
    });
```

Or, if `ProbeAuditEntity` is a class you could do this:

```
//Build the report
var report =
    (from pr in providerRiskLevels
    join nc in newCodes on pr.Provider.ProviderId equals nc.ProviderId
    where pr.RiskCategoryId == RiskCategoryIds.VisibleRisk
        && filterRiskLevelNums.Contains(pr.RiskLevelNum)
        && (filterSpecialtyId == 0 
            || pr.Provider.Specialty.SpecialtyId == filterSpecialtyId)
    select new ProbeAuditEntity
    {
        ProviderId = x.RiskLevel.Provider.ProviderId,
        ProviderName = x.RiskLevel.Provider.Name,
        ProviderCode = x.RiskLevel.Provider.ProviderCode,
        SpecialtyName = x.RiskLevel.Provider.Specialty.Name,
        SpecialtyCode = x.RiskLevel.Provider.Specialty.SpecialtyCode,
        VisibleRisk = x.RiskLevel.RiskScore,
        NewCodes = nc.Codes.OrderByDescending(c => c.Volumn).Select(c => c.ProcedureCode).Take(5)
    })
    .ToList();

report
.ForEach(x => x.NewCodes = x.NewCodes.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(<DefaultProcedureCodeHere>, 5)).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I went with the first option, and also combined the two, now very similar, statements "newCodes=" and "report="